# mfc blink control (custom checklistctrl)

Tags: c++, mfc

I am making an MFC Custom List Control ( inner draw radio button )

but it draws so weird.
radio button appears as blink or erase.

how can I fix this?

here is my code
--> vfcxxx is xxx same things
--> cell struct have string, row, btn data

```
#include "checklistctrl.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CCheckListCtrl, CListCtrl)

CCheckListCtrl::CCheckListCtrl(): CListCtrl()
{
    visibleMaxRow = visibleMinRow = 0;
}

CCheckListCtrl::~CCheckListCtrl()
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCheckListCtrl, CListCtrl)
    ON_WM_DRAWITEM()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void CCheckListCtrl::DrawItem(_In_ LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
    static int tmp = 1;
    int cnt = lpDrawItemStruct->itemID;
    VfcLong tmpnum = -1;
    LONG prev_left = lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem.left;

    LV_COLUMN column_data;
    memset(&column_data, 0, sizeof(LV_COLUMN));
    column_data.mask = LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_FMT;

    for(int column_index = 0; GetColumn(column_index, &column_data); column_index++)
    {
        RECT tempRC;
        {
            tempRC.top  = lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem.top;
            tempRC.bottom = lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem.bottom;
            tempRC.left  = (prev_left);
            tempRC.right = (prev_left += column_data.cx);
        }

        LV_ITEM tempLI;
        wchar_t buffer[256];
        {
            tempLI.mask   = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_PARAM;
            tempLI.iItem  = lpDrawItemStruct->itemID;
            tempLI.iSubItem  = column_index;
            tempLI.pszText  = buffer;
            tempLI.cchTextMax = sizeof(buffer);
            VERIFY(GetItem(&tempLI));
        }

        CString tmpChk = buffer;
        CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);

        if( (tmpnum = isInsert(defaultGroup, cnt)) != -1)
        {
            pDC->FillSolidRect(&tempRC, RGB(255, 255, 255));
            pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));
            tempRC.left += 2;
            pDC->DrawText(buffer, wcslen(buffer), &tempRC, DT_LEFT);
        }
        else if( (tmpnum = isInsert(radioGroup, cnt)) != -1)
        {
            radioCell cell = radioGroup[tmpnum];
            pDC->FillSolidRect(&tempRC, RGB(cell.color[0], cell.color[1], cell.color[2]));
            pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(125, 125, 125));
            tempRC.left += 2;
            pDC->DrawText(buffer, wcslen(buffer), &tempRC, DT_LEFT);
        }
        else 
        {
            pDC->FillSolidRect(&tempRC, RGB(255, 255, 255));
            pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));
            tempRC.left += 2;
            pDC->DrawText(buffer, wcslen(buffer), &tempRC, DT_LEFT);
        }
    }
    setVisibleRowNumber();
    setVisibleAttrRadioButton(prev_left);
}

VfcLong CCheckListCtrl::isInsert(VfcArray<radioCell> arr, VfcLong row)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if( arr[i].row == row)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

VfcLong CCheckListCtrl::isInsert(VfcArray<baseCell> arr, VfcLong row)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if( arr[i].row == row)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

VfcVoid CCheckListCtrl::insertRadioCell
(VfcLong groupId, VfcLong row, VfcString layName, VfcString data, VfcShort color[3], VfcBool isStart)
{
    USES_CONVERSION;
    InsertItem(row, A2W(layName.c_str()));
    SetItem(row, 1, LVIF_TEXT, A2W(data.c_str()), 0, 0, 0, NULL );
    //SetItem(row, 2, LVIF_TEXT, _T(""), 0, 0, 0, NULL );

    radioCell cell = { row, layName, data, groupId, color[0], color[1], color[2], new CButton()};
    radioGroup.pushTail(cell);

    CRect tmp;
    tmp.top = 0;
    tmp.bottom = 19;
    tmp.left = 280;
    tmp.right = 350;

    if (isStart)
    {
        cell.btn->Create(_T("select"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_GROUP | BS_OWNERDRAW, tmp, this, row);
    }
    else
    {
        cell.btn->Create(_T("select"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | BS_OWNERDRAW, tmp, this, row);
    }
}

VfcVoid CCheckListCtrl::insertSingleCell(VfcLong row, VfcString layName, VfcString data)
{
    baseCell cell = { row, layName, data};
    singleGrop.pushTail(cell);
    USES_CONVERSION;
    InsertItem(row, A2W(layName.c_str()));
    SetItem(row, 1, LVIF_TEXT, A2W(data.c_str()), 0, 0, 0, NULL );
}

VfcVoid CCheckListCtrl::insertDefaultCell(VfcLong row, VfcString data)
{
    baseCell cell = { row, "default", data};
    singleGrop.pushTail(cell);
    InsertItem(row, _T("default"));
    USES_CONVERSION;
    SetItem(row, 1, LVIF_TEXT, A2W(data.c_str()), 0, 0, 0, NULL );
}

VfcVoid CCheckListCtrl::setVisibleRowNumber()
{
    visibleMinRow = GetScrollPos(SB_VERT);
    visibleMaxRow = visibleMinRow + 12;
}

VfcVoid CCheckListCtrl::setVisibleAttrRadioButton(VfcLong left)
{
    VfcLong row, cnt = 0, cnt2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < radioGroup.size(); i++)
    {
        row = radioGroup[i].row;
        if( row >= visibleMinRow && row <= visibleMaxRow)
        {
            radioGroup[i].btn->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
            radioGroup[i].btn->SetWindowPos(NULL, left, (row - visibleMinRow + 1) * 19 + 5, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
            radioGroup[i].btn->RedrawWindow();
        }
        else
        {
            radioGroup[i].btn->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: While I'm not sure what you're trying to do, you might be better off using a Custom Draw List control.

Comment: I'm find problem. That's two control's( listctrl, radiobutton ) overlapped after continuously call listcontrol's drawitem before listctrl inner scrolling. so, I want know this " why continuously call drawitem this time? " .